# Consolidate two switch statements into single function

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have the following Image where I can utilizing two switch statements, so I wanted to see if there is a way for me to improve the performance, or trim down the functions into a single function, I have never done this before, so it will be a learning experience.

So I have the function:

```
@ViewBuilder func viewForPlace(_ place: Place) -> some View {
  Image("map-pin")
        .renderingMode(.template)
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
        .foregroundColor(place.show ? .red : Color.init(UIColor(hexString: mapAnnotationColor(place.category))))
        .onTapGesture {
            if !place.show {
                tapOnMapAnnotation(
                    place: place
                )
            }
        }
        .overlay(
            Image(mapAnnotationIcon(place.category)).renderingMode(.template).resizable().frame(width: 10, height: 8).foregroundColor(.white).padding(.bottom, 15)
        )
}
```

It utilizes the following switch statements:

```
// MARK: - SET MAP ANNOTATION COLOR
private func mapAnnotationColor(_ category: String) -> String {
    switch category {
    case "Route":
        return "#6A798E"
    case "Scenic Area":
        return "#006994"
    case "Attraction":
        return "#00954C"
    case "Hospitality":
        return "#6D5B97"
    case "Landmark":
        return "#5D5639"
    default:
        return "#FFFFFF"
    }
}

// MARK: - SET MAP ANNOTATION ICON
private func mapAnnotationIcon(_ category: String) -> String {
    switch category {
    case "Route":
        return "car-side"
    case "Scenic Area":
        return "camera"
    case "Attraction":
        return "people-group"
    case "Hospitality":
        return "bed"
    case "Landmark":
        return "landmark-flag"
    default:
        return "NA"
    }
}
```

Is there a clear way to write this code where I don't have to utilize 2 switch statements or is it possible to have everything under one function?

Comment: Do not use 8 bits per color channel; that is for very old monitors.

Comment: You could return a tuple or struct containing the color and icon values in a single switch but whatever solution you use I would recommend creating an enum for your categories

Comment: What would you recommend @Jessy?

Comment: @theMap This is too big a topic for comments. Just never allow yourself to use them again, researching whatever is necessary to allow yourself to support that choice.

Comment: @Jessy, while I agree that 8-bit per channel color is kind of limiting, if a design constraint is to match the color theme of a website, that maybe how they are specified there, so I wouldn't go so far as to say "never do that."  As for @theMap's question regarding what to use instead, you could specify the color as a `CGColor`, which uses `CGFloat` (aka `Double`) for the color channel values, though you should read up on `CGColor` because RGB(A) is hardly the only option.

Comment: Or you could use a color picker to select the colors and drop color literals into your source code... kind of cool feature of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Define the necessary values upfront and then use them later.

```swift
@ViewBuilder func view(place: Place) -> some View {
  let mapAnnotation = MapAnnotation(category: place.category)
  Image("map-pin")
    .renderingMode(.template)
    .resizable()
    .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
    .foregroundColor(place.show ? .red : mapAnnotation.color)
    .onTapGesture {
      if !place.show {
        tapOnMapAnnotation(
          place: place
        )
      }
    }
    .overlay(
      mapAnnotation.image.renderingMode(.template).resizable().frame(width: 10, height: 8).foregroundColor(.white).padding(.bottom, 15)
    )
}
```

```swift
struct MapAnnotation {
  init(category: Place.Category?) {
    switch category {
    case .route:
      self.init(pixelArtColorFromThe1990s: "#6A798E", imageName: "car-side")
    case .scenicArea:
      self.init(pixelArtColorFromThe1990s: "#006994", imageName: "camera")
    case .attraction:
      self.init(pixelArtColorFromThe1990s: "#00954C", imageName: "people-group")
    case .hospitality:
      self.init(pixelArtColorFromThe1990s: "#6D5B97", imageName: "bed")
    case .landmark:
      self.init(pixelArtColorFromThe1990s: "#5D5639", imageName: "landmark-flag")
    case nil:
      self.init(pixelArtColorFromThe1990s: "FFFFFF", imageName: "NA")
    }
  }

  let image: Image
  let color: Color

  private init(
    pixelArtColorFromThe1990s: String,
    imageName: String
  ) {
    color = .init(UIColor(hexString: pixelArtColorFromThe1990s))
    image = .init(imageName)
  }
}
```

```swift
struct Place {
  …
  let category: Category?

  enum Category {
    case route, scenicArea, attraction, hospitality, landmark
  }
}
```

Comment: `private init(pixelArtColorFromThe1990s: ...`  While I decided not to do it in my answer, trying to keep fairly close to OP's representations, I do like that you replaced the stringly `category` with an `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, they can be combined into a single function:

```swift
private func mapAnnotationAttributes(_ category: String) -> (String, String)
{
    switch category {
        case "Route"      : return ("car-side",      "#6A798E")
        case "Scenic Area": return ("camera",        "#006994")
        case "Attraction" : return ("people-group",  "#00954C")
        case "Hospitality": return ("bed",           "#6D5B97")
        case "Landmark"   : return ("landmark-flag", "#5D5639")

        default: return ("NA", "#FFFFFF")
    }
}
```

The issue is that you use the values in two different methods on `Image`, so you'll need call `mapAnnotationAttribtes` prior so you have the results to pass to those methods.

```swift
@ViewBuilder func viewForPlace(_ place: Place) -> some View {
  let (annotationIconName, annotationRGBString) = mapAnnotationAttributes(place.category)
  return Image("map-pin")
        .renderingMode(.template)
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
        .foregroundColor(place.show ? .red : Color.init(UIColor(hexString: annotationRGBString)))
        .onTapGesture {
            if !place.show {
                tapOnMapAnnotation(
                    place: place
                )
            }
        }
        .overlay(
            Image(annotationIconName).renderingMode(.template).resizable().frame(width: 10, height: 8).foregroundColor(.white).padding(.bottom, 15)
        )
}
```

It occurs to me though that, at least in the given code, you don't actually need the `String`s.  Maybe you need them somewhere else for some reason, but in the code you provided, what you need is an icon `Image` and a `Color`.  In my opinion your view `viewForPlace` code would be more readable if you just returned those from `mapAnnotationAttribute`.

```swift
private func mapAnnotationAttributes(_ category: String) -> (Image, Color)
{
    let attribs: (String, String)
    switch category {
        case "Route"      : attribs = ("car-side",      "#6A798E")
        case "Scenic Area": attribs = ("camera",        "#006994")
        case "Attraction" : attribs = ("people-group",  "#00954C")
        case "Hospitality": attribs = ("bed",           "#6D5B97")
        case "Landmark"   : attribs = ("landmark-flag", "#5D5639")

        default: attribs = ("NA", "#FFFFFF")
    }

    let icon = Image(attribs.0)
    let color = Color.init(UIColor(hexString: attribs.1))

    return (icon, color)
}
```

Then `viewForPlace` becomes:

```swift
@ViewBuilder func viewForPlace(_ place: Place) -> some View {
  let (annotationIcon, annotationColor) = mapAnnotationAttributes(place.category)
  return Image("map-pin")
        .renderingMode(.template)
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
        .foregroundColor(place.show ? .red : annotationColor)
        .onTapGesture {
            if !place.show {
                tapOnMapAnnotation(
                    place: place
                )
            }
        }
        .overlay(
            annotationIcon.renderingMode(.template).resizable().frame(width: 10, height: 8).foregroundColor(.white).padding(.bottom, 15)
        )
}
```

Now if I can engage in a bit of mind-reading (always questionable territory), I suspect that your real motivation in wanting to unify those functions is to make it easier to maintain the attributes, maybe adding new categories.  If that's the case, you could eliminate the switch entirely, and use a global (or static) constant `Dictionary`:

```swift
fileprivate let annotationAttributes: [String: (iconName: String, rgbHex: String)] =
[
    "Route"      : ("car-side",      "#6A798E"),
    "Scenic Area": ("camera",        "#006994"),
    "Attraction" : ("people-group",  "#00954C"),
    "Hospitality": ("bed",           "#6D5B97"),
    "Landmark"   : ("landmark-flag", "#5D5639"),
]

private func mapAnnotationAttributes(_ category: String) -> (Image, Color)
{
    let (iconName, rgbHex) = annotationAttributes[category]
        ?? ("NA", "#FFFFFF")

    let icon = Image(iconName)
    let color = Color.init(UIColor(hexString: rgbHex))

    return (icon, color)
}
```

Also if the icon image is only ever modified by the properties you specify in `viewForPlace`, you could apply them in `mapAnnotationAttributes` and simpifly the calling code even more.  But if you want to re-use it with, for example, different foreground color, or whatever, it might better to keep the application of those modifiers in the caller.

Others suggested creating an `enum` for your category.  Although I chose not to do that up to this point, staying as close as possible to your data representations, I do agree that's a good suggestion:

```swift
enum Category: String, Hashable
{
    
    case route       = "Route"
    case scenicArea  = "Scenic Area"
    case attraction  = "Attraction"
    case hospitality = "Hospitality"
    case landmark    = "Landmark"
}
    
fileprivate let annotationAttributes: [Category: (iconName: String, rgbHex: String)] =
[
    .route      : ("car-side",      "#6A798E"),
    .scenicArea : ("camera",        "#006994"),
    .attraction : ("people-group",  "#00954C"),
    .hospitality: ("bed",           "#6D5B97"),
    .landmark   : ("landmark-flag", "#5D5639"),
]

private func mapAnnotationAttributes(_ category: Category) -> (Image, Color)
{
    let (iconName, rgbHex) = annotationAttributes[category]
        ?? ("NA", "#FFFFFF")

    let icon = Image(iconName)
    let color = Color.init(UIColor(hexString: rgbHex))

    return (icon, color)
}
```

The up-side, and it's a big up-side, in my opinion, is the type-safety you get from having a distinct type for `Category` rather than a `String` that could be anything.

The down-side is that now you're back to maintaining two pieces of code when you want to add a new category: one for the category itself, and one for the mapping to icons and colors, and that's true whether you use a `switch` or a `Dictionary`.  It might seem better to use a `switch` in this case because it enforces that you cover all the cases... except that using a `default` case kind of prevents that, so you'd need to get rid of the default case.  You want the compiler error when you don't cover all the cases explicitly.

It comes down to who is in control of defining categories.

If it's your code, then what you want is an `enum` with a `switch` instead of a `Dictionary` and **no** `default` case.  That way, when you add a new category, the compiler will inform you of all the places you need to update `switch` statements.  Hopefully it's just one `switch`, but maybe at some point you do some non-UI stuff based on category.  Then you'd have another `switch` somewhere.

On the other hand, if a server is in control of defining the categories, and assuming you have to do something reasonable when it eventually sends one your code doesn't know about, staying with `String` is quite reasonable, though please define some constants for them, and use them instead of string literals in your code to reduce opportunities for typos to creep in. In this case you can still use the `Dictionary` - though you might want to `assert` or at least log when you get an unknown category.  You *could* still use an `enum`, and at least get some of the type-safety benefits, but you'd need to define a case to handle unknown category strings from the server. That doesn't help you much with maintenance in terms of knowing about new categories from the server, but because something like `case unknown` is a specific case, when you do discover there are new categories you need to handle, once you add them to the `enum`, at least you'll get compiler errors for all corresponding `switch` statements that need updating.